# Issues connecting to Progress database via ODBC in published Web Application

Tags: asp.net, odbc, 32-bit, openedge, progress-db

I am having issue trying to get my Web Application published and running correctly on our IIS server.

When I test from within Visual Studio 2015 with the same ODBC driver setups, everything works fine.  It is only once I try to publish the Web Application and access it off the IIS webserver in a browser that I am getting an issues.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 v14.0.25431.01 Update 3

The IIS server is a 64-bit Windows 2016 server

The ODBC driver is a Progress OpenEdge 11.6 driver - 32 Bit

The ODBC connection is setup using the 32-bit ODBC Manager found in c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32

I came across many forums that say to make sure that the ODBC driver is setup correctly, and using the correct ODBC manager, which it is.

I also came across some posts that reference compiling the Web Application and specifying in the Configuration manager to use x86 instead of Any CPU.  x86 is not an option when I go into the configuration manager.

I am at a loss as to how to resolve this error so that I can access the new Web Applications from the IIS server.

The error I get is...

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:
>
> [OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application]
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode) +1358681
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +78

Any suggestions, advice, recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is what the error message try to say (maybe a bit unclear):

> ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

That means that your are trying to use a 32-bit ODBC driver with the 64-bit version of IIS, and it's not possible use 32-bit drivers/libraries in 64-bit applications (not just for IIS, but for any Windows application).

You have no problem with VS 2015 because it's a [32-bit application](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Visual-Studio-2015-still-a-32-bit-application), so the driver and the application match. You need to install the 64-bit ODBC driver for IIS and configure a 64-bit ODBC.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I was not sure if I would be able to use the 32-bit driver on the server or not.  I will go about trying to get a proper 64-bit driver and see if that will resolve all my issues.